# OPENSUSE HDMI monitor not recognized

Tags: linux, opensuse, xrandr, gpu, hdmi

I have problem with my integr. graphic card in my laptop MSI Summit 14- Intel IRIS XE.

Display at laptop working fine, but if i plug external monitor to hdmi, nothink is recognized. Cable is ok, because on windows is working.

localhost:/home/milan # xrandr

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

What can i do? Please can u help me?

`localhost:/home/milan # lspci -v` [selected output]

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 12e0
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
        Memory at 601c000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
        Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
        Capabilities: [320] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)
        Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: You could have edited your question with a selected extract of `lspci -v`. Actually, something like `lspci -v | grep -i -A20 vga` would probably have been sufficient. I have moved some appropriate lines into your question.